# Is electro-resuscitate a word? Can it be used?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I thought I would find the word in the dictionary. However, after doing a Google search I found out I was wrong.

The term *electro-resuscitation* has been used though:

> ... Giovanni Aldini, Professor of Physics at Bolognia, gave public
>   demonstrations of electro-resuscitation ...

[Sources.](https://www.google.com.tw/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=electro-resuscitate)

Is electro-resuscitate a word? Would it okay to use it in writing?

The context is informal/literary writing. Here's an example:

> She was like a patient being electro-resucitated multiple times.

Comment: That same book also says: electrical resuscitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not a common term, but it is made of two common parts so would probably be understood.

If I understand the meaning correctly, we would usually say "defibrillation" (attaching electrodes to a person whose heart is not beating steadily, and applying a shock to them to restore normal heart function)

In your example "a patient being defibrillated multiple times" or just "shocked" (if there is sufficient context to understand "shocked" to mean "electrically shocked in a medical context)